# the difference between "is a not unusual factor" and "is not an unusual factor"

Tags: grammar

> The working mother is now a not unusual factor in a child's home life.

I was confused about this sentence because I think "The working mother is NOT an unusual factor in a child's home life." sounds more natural to me. I asked my grammar teacher about it and she said the sentence means that "The mother is a usual factor" rather than "The mother is not a factor." Can't the  word "not" put before "a" to negate "unusual"?

Comment: She is a **factor** in a child's life **which is not unusual** - in other words, a lot of mothers go out to work.

Comment: [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258029/two-questions-about-double-negation-expressions) discusses "not uncommon", which is similar to "not unusual".

Comment: I guess you should analyze the (quite weird) sentence "The working mother is now NOT a NOT unusual factor in a child's home life.".

Comment: Your version would make sense and is not wrong, but the point of the sentence is to stress that the _situation_ is common, not to tell us something that the _mother_ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways of phrasing the sentence are clear and natural, and mean the same thing -- that the working mother is a factor, and that this situation is common.

Your suggested wording is more common.